# xcode alloutput window doesn't work [picture included]

Tags: xcode, printf, scanf

I inputed 1111 but it only shows the first 1 
I tried to uninstall and install xcode again but it didn't work
what should i do please help

```
int main()
{

    int num;

    printf("input: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("%d",num);
    return 0;
}
```

output

> input: 1
>
> 1111

Answer (score 3):

You should with a begginer tutorial in ObjectiveC.

If you want to "printf" a variable (integer in this case) you have to do:

```
NSLog(@"My number is %d",num);
```

If you want to "printf" a NSString you should do:

```
NSLog(@"My string is %@",String);
```